# Sending data (BytesIO buffer) through a Pipe works but causes a Fatal Python exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pipe, multiprocessor

Using Python 2.7 on Windows, the following code works but causes a problem with msvc.

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def tmpPlot(conn):
  plt.plot([1,2,4,2])
  plt.title("title")

  buf = io.BytesIO()
  plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
  buf.seek(0)
  conn.send(plt.imread(buf))
  conn.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
  p = Process(target=tmpPlot, args=(child_conn,))
  p.start()

  imgData = parent_conn.recv()

  imgplt = plt2.imshow(imgData)

  plt2.show()
```

Here is the error:

[image: MSVC Error]

Followed by pythonw.exe has stopped working message:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    59bd8782
  Fault Module Name:    python27.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.7.14150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59bd877e
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 0014098b
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: ac4a
  Additional Information 2: 817fddeef0c50f6183a834229ec12634
  Additional Information 3: 3df9
  Additional Information 4: 47d9390827b4b422b52d14c0c48ab5d9

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

Comment: This seems to depend on the use of `pyplot` within the thread. See [this simplified example](https://pastebin.com/E6PYkcvv), which should work fine. If you then uncomment the pyplot line, the error is raised. This is all independend on using the buffer.

Comment: Additional testing showed that adding a delay after the conn.send(data) statement avoids the error.  Is there a more elegant way to detect that the send command is finished? or wait until it is done instead of an arbitrary amount of time?

Comment: the delay used is time.sleep(.001), it doesn't seem to matter how long it sleeps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a short sleep command seems to do the trick...

```
conn.send(plt.imread(buf))
time.sleep(.001)
conn.close
```

Not elegant but works.