# how can I rotate the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is an example of a picture I drew.

```
   /      /
  /      /
 /      /
```

I want to rotate it like this:

```
l     l
l     l
l     l
```

What should I do?

This is my code.

plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))

route_start=[34.45, 126.05]

route_end = [34.4, 126.1]

plt.scatter(df.lon.values, df.lat.values, alpha=0.3)

plt.plot([route_start[1],route_end[1]],[route_start[0],route_end[0]],'b-')

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

I wanna [1] image to [2] image.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFYsr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGu3r.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `scipy.ndimage`.

Here's the code, you hadn't provide enough information about your problem, so just example:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
new_img = ndimage.rotate(img, <angle>, reshape=True)
```

`new_img` is rotated to given angle. You can play with `reshape=True/False`.

Don't forget to mark this as answer if it helps you to solve your problem, and if any queries ask in comment.

Comment: Thanks.
This is my code.

plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))

 

route_start=[34.45, 126.05]

route_end = [34.4, 126.1]

 

plt.scatter(df.lon.values, df.lat.values, alpha=0.3)

plt.plot([route_start[1], route_end[1]], [route_start[0], route_end[0]],'b-')

Comment: @강윤희 please edit your question and add them!

Comment: I edited it. Please confirm. uu ..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Maybe you are trying to rotate an image. If you are actually trying to rotate a plot or an image this should help. This answer was adapted from the following posts:

[Rotate image post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401812/matplotlib-rotate-image-file-by-x-degrees)
[Plot to image IO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007787/matplotlib-savefig-to-cstreamio-then-load-the-data-into-another-matplotlib-plot)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
import io

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.plot([0, 0.5], [0, 1])
ax.plot([1, 1.5], [0, 1])

buff = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format='png')
buff.seek(0)

img = plt.imread(buff)
rotated_img = ndimage.rotate(img, 30)

show_img = plt.imshow(rotated_img)
plt.axis('off')
```