# How do I print scatter plots in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I created a pandas dataframe using the below code. (See the extra code `and plt.show()` which is there to create a new plot every time or else we get one plot with all of them in the same plot)

```
%matplotlib inline

pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[
        col,
        plt.scatter(data[col], data['SalePrice']) and plt.show()]
    for col in data.columns]),
    columns=['Feature', 'Scatter Plot']
)
```

But what I get is this

[image: a pandas dataframe with some no-so-useful information about scatter plots]

And at the end of the dataframe, I get all the scatter plots separately.

What I want is, for those graphs to get printed inline, inside the columns, just like the other values.

Comment: I don't think this can be done.   Pandas dataframes are not designed to handle objects like this.  You can store the object, but to have print graphically I don't think pandas will do this.

Comment: There _may_ be a way to do this using pandas styling and `to_html`, but it would still need to be viewed in a web browser, as in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824522/dynamically-serving-a-matplotlib-image-to-the-web-using-python), not in-line