# Jinja rendering matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jinja2

I am looking at combining matplotlib and jinja2 to produce html pages.

What I do now is just including an image previously produced by matplotlib as a reference in my html page. The result is really static.

I've seen related questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824522/dynamically-serving-a-matplotlib-image-to-the-web-using-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515278/plot-matplotlib-on-the-web), but none related to matplotlib/jinja integration (ultimately I'd like interactivity but It does not seem to be simple enough for me).

Is there any alternative to what I do ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'really static' and 'interactivity'?  do you want to modify plots on the client side?

Comment: why don't you render the image files and then (dynamically) reference them in jinja img src? For interactive charts look at [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) or [plotly](https://plot.ly/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ipython notebook from v1.x uses `jinja2`.

You can create inline images in the notebook and then convert it to a static html with `nbconvert`. You can provide custom css and you can customise the output html to hide code cells, cell numbers, ...